# How to convert array contents into a single string C

Tags: c

So the following is a sandbox program. The issue I'm having is combining an array into a single string. I would like to do something similar to the code below:

```
 for (i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++)
    {
            string += A[i]; // print array
    }
```

The goal is to run a command using popen() and capture the output into a single string. the reason for this is so that I can return the output to a separate function for example:

```
run_command()
{
     return output;
}

main()
{
    run_command()
}
```

Now the exact code that the "sandbox" program is using is down below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        FILE *in;
        extern FILE *popen();
        char buff[512];
        int i, size_of_array;
        char A[512][512];

        in = popen("ls -lt", "r"); // run command

        i = 0;
        while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL) // get output into buff
        {
                strcpy(A[i], buff); // copy buff into array
                i ++;
        }

        pclose(in);

        size_of_array = i; // get length or size of array

        for (i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++)
        {
                printf("A[%d]= %s", i, A[i]); // print array
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I apologize if this is a noob question, I appreciate the help, thank you!

Comment: TL;DR. But `sprintf` might help.

Comment: C does not have a string type.

Comment: `char outbuf[512*512], *sp = outbuf; size_t len = 0; for (i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++){ strcpy(sp += len, A[i]); len = strlen(A[i]); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcat`, `strcat_s`, or `strncat` append a string at the end of a destination string (cf. [cppreference for strcat](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat)). The only thing is to make sure that the destination buffer is large enough. `strcat_s` can be used to avoid buffer overflows, but is not available on all systems. `strncat` can be used to avoid buffer overflows, too, yet one needs to track the length of the string within the buffer:

```
#define maxSize 512*512

char result[maxSize] = { 0x0 };
for (int i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++) {
    strcat(result, A[i]);
}
```

or:

```
char result[maxSize] = { 0x0 };
for (int i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++) {
    strcat_s(result, maxSize, A[i]);
}
```

or:

```
char result[maxSize] = { 0x0 };
for (int i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++) {
    strncat(result, A[i], maxSize-strlen(result)-1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Stephan, and Eugene both solutions worked! Ill be using strcat_s. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: strcat_s() isn't available on Linux systems.  strncat() is more portable.  I would upvote this one if a solution with strncat() is made available too.

Comment: @Ricardo Branco: right; added a `strncat`-solution, too.

Comment: It's ok.  It could be optimized to avoid the repeated calls to strlen().